# Adding context menu to Dialog in Kendo for Angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In this [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyabvn?file=app/app.component.ts) I have a Kendo for Angular dialog that contains a context menu.

If you right click, you should see the context menu, however it is shown behind the Dialog. How to change the context menu `z-index` to show it on top? I tried adding a style but it didn't work.

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

      <kendo-dialog title="Menu inside" *ngIf="opened" (close)="close()">

       <div #target1>Right click to see the context menu</div>
       <kendo-contextmenu style="z-index:20000" [target]="target1">
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 111"></kendo-menu-item>
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 222"></kendo-menu-item>
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 333"></kendo-menu-item>           
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 444"></kendo-menu-item>           
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 555"></kendo-menu-item>           
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 666"></kendo-menu-item> 
               <kendo-menu-item text="Option 777"></kendo-menu-item>           
      </kendo-contextmenu>

          <kendo-dialog-actions>
              <button kendoButton (click)="close()" [primary]="true">Close</button>
          </kendo-dialog-actions>
      </kendo-dialog>
    `,
    styles: [` 
                .k-dialog { z-index:2 !important } 
                .k-overlay { z-index:1 !important }
            `],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {

    public opened: bool = true;

    public close() {
      this.opened = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to change the dialog z-index with `k-dialog-wrapper`

```
.k-dialog-wrapper { z-index:2 !important }
```